# Does fail2ban do Windows?

Tags: windows, security

Can anyone recommend a fail2ban-like tool for a Windows OS?  I've got a couple of Windows Media servers that get hammered with brute force authentication attempts.  I would like to plug these authentication failures into some kind of blocking tool.

Comment: Could you provide some clarification? What are you trying to accomplish? What version of Windows? Are you trying to block bad logins to PCs, network shares, Terminal Servers, IIS-hosted pages, etc?

Comment: Clarified my question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I know of no tool that will do this "out of the box". I wrote a script to do something like this with failed OpenSSH logons on Windows, but I can't share it with you because it "belongs" to the Customer for whom I wrote it.

Having said that, it was a simple VBScript program that had an event log sink to watch for new failed logons and, if enough happened in a time window, add an IP route (using the "route" command) to route traffic to the offending IP address to a "MS Loopback Adapter" on the system.

For other types of logs, it would be a fairly trivial matter to write. Since I didn't have IPtables on Windows, the loopback adapter seemed like the next best thing. (You can't do a "route x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1" on Windows-- you need an adapter to route the traffic to, because the 127.0.0.1 loopback isn't a "real" interface on Windows.)

(If you want something like this written, contact me out-of-band and we can discuss the specifics of such an arrangement.)

Edit:

### [I decided to write something to do this and I've released it under a Free license.](https://serverfault.com/questions/43360/cygwin-sshd-autoblock-failed-logins/43900#43900)

Answer (score 5):

I recently installed IPBan on Windows Server 2019:
https://github.com/digitalruby/ipban

And it's radically decreased number of failed RDP logins:
[image: Failed RDP logons]

Comment: what's the name of this "dashboard"?

Comment: @Kreker, that's Discover app in the Kibana. The data is sent by Winlogbeat.

Comment: Ipban runs on Linux and windows ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this project - [ts_block](https://github.com/EvanAnderson/ts_block)

I'm using it and thus far its terrific (Windows Server 2008 R2 RDS, system is behind a firewall but I didn't feel like using an ssl vpn gateway to the server)

Answer (score 3):

[EvlWatcher](https://github.com/devnulli/EvlWatcher)

**What's EvlWatcher?**

> It's basically a fail2ban for windows. Its goals are also mainly what we love about fail2ban:

```
pre-configured
no-initial-fucking-around-with-scripts-or-config-files
install-and-forget
```

Comment: always the first thing I install on a cloud server

Answer (score 1):

[wail2ban](https://github.com/glasnt/wail2ban) claims to be a Windows port of fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool called RdpGuard (https://rdpguard.com) that starts at $79 and appears like it might work.  I haven't tested it yet, but might give it a go for my SMTP solution.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to have used the product, before you make the recommendation.

Comment: A VM hosting company I started using includes a copy on their Windows VMs.  It does the trick, and there are hundreds of firewall entries after just a few weeks.

Comment: I've been using this lately and it works extremely well. I recommend it. I love how it's an easy install with a GUI interface. There are no scripts to set up and run. It's all-inclusive and allows a lot of auto-blocking beyond just RDP, such as SMTP, MySQL, MS SQL, and more if there are failed logins. Very configurable. I have no affiliation with the company that makes this program, just FYI.

Comment: Ipban is free and has a one click install

Answer (score 1):

You may check [Win2ban](https://itefix.net/win2ban) which is a Fail2ban implementation for Windows systems. It is a packaging of Fail2ban, Python, Cygwin, Winlogbeat and many other related tools to make it a complete and ready-to-use solution for brute-force attack protection.

NB! We are the developer of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like fail2ban runs on windows at all, as it requires iptables which is only available on Linux.

However, I would suggest that you **block everything and white-list** only the IPs/names you want to be able to connect to the server(s) in question, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I've found is [QaaSWall](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qaaswall-window/), I haven't tested it yet, but I will be in the next day or so.

Comment: Doesn't work on x64 actually, @Evan I'm using your script