# Fail2ban for Windows 7?

Tags: security, windows-firewall, windows-7, ip-blocking

My server is getting hit pretty hard by (what appears to be) script kiddies in China. I'm just looking for some thoughts/ideas on how to potentially setup some type of Fail2ban proc?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/43360/cygwin-sshd-autoblock-failed-logins/43900#43900

Answer (score 0):

[An answer to a similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/43360/cygwin-sshd-autoblock-failed-logins/43900#43900) links to a tool to protect Cygwin's sshd in Windows.

As [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) works for all sorts of programs that write (login) log files, this won't necessarily be adequate solution. As you didn't specify what service are you securing, I assume that it is ssh...

Comment: I've updated sshd_block for Windows Vista / 2008 / 7 / 2008 R2 support.

Answer (score 0):

IPSec should fill your needs and it's free/included in Windows.  Nothing fancy here, just a simple deny rule and a filter matching the offending IP Address spaces...