# How can I allow RDP access to a Windows 2008R2 server from one IP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

I've been trying to secure RDP to a new Windows 2008R2 server (using Windows Firewall) by only allowing RDP traffic from one IP address.

Under the "Computers" tab, it seems I can only allow user or computer authentications when the server is set to only allow secure connections.

So, I go to the "General" tab and under "Action" I set to "allow the connection if it is secure". That's when I get shut out, cannot reconnect over RDP and have to rebuild (this is a Rackspace cloud server so easily done).

Where am I going wrong? I haven't done anything to my local workstation (which I'm assuming I have to) as I can't find anything in the RDP client to change regarding encrypting the connection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to set this rule in the RDP configuration page, you should be setting it in the firewall configuration page.

Basically, you need to click start, search for `Windows Firewall` and follow the screen shots that I've provided below. You'll be adding a Remote IP Allow rule to the pre-defined RDP-IN rule that should already be enabled.

***Edit: Added screenshots***

**Step 1**: Open the Windows Firewall with Advanced Configuration

[image: Firewall in Start Menu]

**Step 2**: Locate the Remote Desktop rule that's currently enabled and edit it.

[image: Inbound Rules]

**Step 3**: In the `Scope` tab, change the allowed Remote IPs field to whatever you want. This is the source address that you wish to restrict.

[image: Remote Source IP]