# Attempt to access SQL Server with the user SA

Tags: sql, sql-server, login, brute-force-attacks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attempt to access SQL Server with the user SA](https://serverfault.com/questions/271061/attempt-to-access-sql-server-with-the-user-sa)

I'm suffering an attempted invasion by brute force.
A bot is trying to figure out the sa password. How do I restrict logins 3 attempts in SQL Server?

Moreover, I would like to block an IP, how can I do this?

Comment: Is your SQL server exposed directly to the net?

Comment: Use a firewall to block an IP.

Comment: You should whitelist acceptable IPs and block the rest, instead of blacklisting bad ones and allowing all others.

Comment: just use the windows firewall. How can I block an ip using it?

Comment: You should post this on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use a login trigger to restrict access from given ip addresses. I will dig out the code for you.

Technet video on how to do it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/Video/dd898898

Comment: See this link - [http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/66151/]http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/66151/