# fail2ban for windows 2008 RDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, remote-desktop, fail2ban

I'm looking for a solution to make remote desktop more secure.
I'm looking for a fail2ban like for windows and specially for RDP which will block IP in firewall after N failed retries
Any help?

Comment: Why do you ignore the windows included mechanisms to protect RDP servers - i.e. TS Gateway?

Comment: There is freeware option available now https://serverfault.com/questions/282510/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-someone-is-brute-forcing-my-server-password/1068887#1068887

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Windows, The most straightforward option out there (from the ones that I tested) is a commercial solution called [RdpGuard](http://rdpguard.com).

There's also one solution called [IPBan](http://www.digitalruby.com/securing-your-windows-dedicated-server/), although I never tried that one.

You can also secure RDP requiring client certificates, check [this article.](http://www.alkia.net/index.php/faqs/106-how-to-secure-remote-desktop-connections-using-tls-ssl-based-authentication)

More interesting articles about securing RDP against brute force attacks:

[Automatically block RDP attacks on your Windows Server 2008](http://psscripts.blogspot.com/2012/12/automatically-block-rdp-attacks-on-your.html)

[Automatically banning IPs with Windows Firewall after scanning the eventlog](http://nerderies.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/automatically-banning-ips-with-windows.html)

Comment: I've been using RdpGuard for 6 months now, and it's great. It's cheap, and gives you the flexibility of blocking connections via either the Windows Firewall or IPSec policies.