# Only allow remote desktop to connect when password is correct - Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop

Whenever I connect to my VPS, when the wrong credentials are placed in, I am still able to connect but I am directed to a login screen.

This can bring up some potential Bruteforce issue so I would like to only allow connection when credentials are correct.

Incase I am unclear, some screenshots are attached.

Attempt to login with wrong password:

[image: Attempt to login with wrong password]

Would like to block connection when credentials are incorrect, do not want them to be brought to this login screen:

[image: Would like to block connection when credentials are incorrect, do not want them to be brought to this login screen]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ban, slowdown or stop massive login attempts to RDP](https://serverfault.com/questions/314850/ban-slowdown-or-stop-massive-login-attempts-to-rdp)

Comment: That is not what I am trying to achieve, dont want to setup a VPN as I will access my server from lots of location

Comment: Is your server configured to require Network Level Authentication?

Comment: The initial dialog is an NLA dialog. If the host is not configured to use NLA, there should not be an expectation it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Greg Askew,
NLA is the issue after enabled that, it works.