# Any way to see the password for attempted RDP intrusions?

Tags: ip, rdp, rate-limiting

I have a silly person in china (According to IP-Reversal websites) who is trying to login to my machine using RDP. I first noticed this when I found a stream of messages similar to this one:

```
[LAN access from remote] from 117.66.240.198:65086 to 192.168.1.20:3389 Thursday, November 16,2017 10:20:17
[LAN access from remote] from 117.66.240.198:56522 to 192.168.1.20:3389 Thursday, November 16,2017 10:19:00
```

Anyway I am not concerned as he is trying every minute or so to log into Administrator account. I have left it disabled and locked as it was.

```
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  ADMINISTRATOR
Source Workstation: 
Error Code: 0xC000006A
```

I know I could change the Port for RDP to something other than 3389 but I need to stick to this port as my office only allows RDPs to the default one.

I also know that I could setup a VPN but then again this might be an overkill for my case.

I changed windows firewall to allow only RDP connections from a range of IPs but had to revert that as my office uses different ISPs and the IP at any moment could be different than after the next network restart.

I was hoping to see the passwords he is trying to use to brute force his way in.

Also is there anyway for me (using default windows policies) to throttle/ban IPs that send invalid credentials for some time?

Also,
As I have a dynamic IP, first thing I did was restart my router and got a new IP, but apparently the habit is too strong as it didn't take longer than a day for another silly guy to start trying his luck with a new range of IPs and get mine within them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't be a good practice to do what you are requesting for as it would also log any legitimate attempts i.e. actual passwords. Even logging just the failures would log any mistyped passwords, too.

Instead, you could automatically block an IP address after certain amount of failed attempts. See this question: [Does fail2ban do Windows?](https://serverfault.com/q/27757/274176)